# Call substitute for package inside launch file

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently editing a launch file that I moved from one package to another.
I would like to store the package name inside an argument or parameter so that I can easily substitute the name by editing the substitute. I tried something like:  <arg name "config_pkg" default="pkg1" />

Now if I want to call it inside another argument it would look like this:

This throws an error, is there an easy way to fix this or do I have to change all the pkg names everytime they will change?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358420/call-substitute-for-package-inside-launch-file/) by [carlosg](https://answers.ros.org/users/55203/carlosg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

To answer your question lets look at the following example, I hgave the following launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="config_pkg" default="my_pkg"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find $(arg config_pkg))/launch/my_config.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

This launch file will throw you an `RLException` since dollar signs '$' cannot be inside of substitution args like `$(find ...)`

You can use this to change dynamically the node package like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="config_pkg" default="rviz"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="$(arg config_pkg)" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

However bear in mind that what you can do is using enviromental variables:

In a terminal:

```
export my_path="/path/to/your/config/"
```

An in the launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="config_pkg" default="rviz"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(optenv my_path default/path/to/config)/my_config.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

For more information about this you can check the following wiki [page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

Hope that can help you with this problem.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlosg](https://answers.ros.org/users/55203/carlosg/) on 2020-08-01**:
Thanks a lot!